# Corner Radius leaving circular line

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview

After setting border width and corner radius of UIView getting black circular line

[image]

Code:

```
afterSelectFrameView.layer.borderWidth=[slide value];
afterSelectFrameView.layer.cornerRadius=[slide value];
```

Comment: afterSelectFrameView.layer.borderWidth=[slide value];
afterSelectFrameView.layer.cornerRadius=[slide value];

Comment: any help ? or any code snippet that ll solve my problem

Comment: [slide value] depend on slider value.slider value from 0 to 10.

Comment: `afterSelectFrameView.layer.masksToBounds = YES`

Comment: i have tried with both afterSelectFrameView.layer.masksToBounds = YES
and afterSelectFrameView.layer.masksToBounds = NO.but problem is still .actually i have a UIScrollView on that i am adding image view.i try to give corner radius and corner width to that scrollview .

Comment: @Zaph i am making frames arounds images

Comment: What is "corner width"?

Comment: @Zaph its depend on slider value from 0 to 10.

Comment: @Syed You need to provide a question with enough information. What you are trying to accomplish, what you have tried, what you are getting and the actual question. Without that much information a question really can't be answered.

Comment: i am just increasing border width and corner radius of UIScrollView
on ScrollView i have UIImageView.thats  All. :)

Comment: @Zaph can you provide me your email i send you code at email.

Comment: @SyedMatloobHasnain: send the sample code to ramshadram90@gmail.com.. let me know once you done.

Comment: i have sent you code of classes

Answer (score 1):

Apply mask to bounds

```
[imageView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[imageView.layer setCornerRadius:5.0];
```

setting the border is not necessary, but here is an option for you.

```
[imageView.layer setBorderWidth:0.0f];
```

Comment: This is the correct answer - masking to bounds does it. Just had (and fixed!) the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I use the code below (it is part of a ViewUtilities library) to round the corners on any view.
You could modify it to add parameters for other radii, colors, etc.

```
+(void)AdjustViewEdges:(UIView*)view
{
   [view.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
   [view.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];
   [view.layer setCornerRadius:12.0f];
   [view.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];  
   view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.99 green:0.99 blue:0.99 alpha:1.0];
}

// You will need this as well
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

I don't believe it is giving me the lines you are seeing...but my background colors were different so they may be hidden...

Was this helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this

```
afterSelectFrameView.layer.borderWidth=0.0;

afterSelectFrameView.layer.cornerRadius=[slide value];
```

Happy coding..........